# Makefile disable options when running command

Tags: docker, makefile

I have a makefile called `test` to which I want to be able to pass options and arguments. Something like:

`make test -t 'test number 1'`

This would in theory run the test called 'test number 1' in my docker container.

My problem is that `-t` is considered as an option of the `make` command instead of an option of my `test` program.

So is there any way to disable the options of the `make` command so that the options given are considered as options of the makefile program ?

Comment: How would you run your command is you were not using make? Can you show what you would type on the command line and explain what part of that is fixed and what part should be modified by options? Note: your makefile is probably not called `test` but `Makefile`. It is, maybe, one of the targets defined in `Makefile` that is named `test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Make doesn't work that way and isn't designed for that.  The usual way to pass options into a Makefile is by setting Make variables

```sh
make test DESCRIPTION='test number 1'
```

You can set (default) values in the Makefile and reference these variables like any other value

```
DESCRIPTION := no description set

all: test

test:
        echo "$(DESCRIPTION)"
```